# Regex to Find Replace Beginning and End of String

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3

My skills are very basic. I'm hoping to find a regular expression for **Sublime Text 3** that finds a string by beginning and end. I'd like to keep the middle unchanged and I only want to replace the beginning and the end.

For instance. Search for url with `/shop/` at the beginning and .htm at the end. I'd then like to replace `/shop/` with `/product/` and replace `.htm` with a forward `/`

e.g.

```
http://www.website.com/shop/ford-truck-hitch-extension.htm
```

becomes

```
http://www.website.com/product/ford-truck-hitch-extension/
```

This bit finds the instances but I can't figure out how to replace the beginning and end.

```
shop[^<]+.htm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find this:

```
/shop/(.*?)\.htm
```

And replace with this:

```
/product/\1/
```

Comment: If using VS Code find-replace, use `$1` instead of `\1` in `/product/\1/`

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with a single regex, try:

```
com\/\Kshop(\/.*?)\.htm
```

and replace with:

```
product\1/
```

<kbd>[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/vF7jY9/2)</kbd>

```
  NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  com                      'com'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       Resets the starting point of the reported match
                           ie: Everything that has been matched till this 
                               point won't be changed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  shop                     'shop'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                     '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                    any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  htm                      'htm'
```

To read more about regex, feel free to visit <kbd>[`The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/1519058)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

So, you're not actually looking for the beginning of the string.  You're looking for part of the string after ".com".  As for end of string, `$` will match it.

I would also suggest using two expressions, as it makes the two substitutions more obvious.

Depending on how specific you need to be, the pair of expressions:

```
s|com/shop/|com/product/|
s|\.htm$|/|
```

will do the pair of substitutions you want.  The first will also work on anything that for some reason has the substring "com/shop/" though, so as I said -- if you need to improve the specificity you can.

If you absolutely need to do it in one:

```
s|com/shop/(.*)\.htm$|com/product/\1/|
```

Will select and save all the content between the parenthesis and re-insert it into your final result, allowing you to make the two changes you're looking for.

PS: I'm not sure how sublimetext handles escaping -- some of these (such as the parenthesis or backslash) may require escaping